# XLS save a DataFrame according to user request

Tags: python, pandas, save, xls, indirect-objects

Hallo and happy new 2018 year,

I have some Python/Pandas DataFrames, each of them with a different name, and I'd like to select one of them based on user's entry and save it as .XLS file.

My initial miserable piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\Files\\'


def excel_save(df_name):    
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path +'some_name.xls')
    shares.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
    writer.save()

#Main
df_name=input ('Enter the name of the DataFrame to be saved as XLS ==>')
excel_save(df_name)
```

What I'd like to pass to the excel_save function is the DataFrame that has the name df_name, not a string with the content of df_name variable:

I'd like to save the AAPL DataFrame, not an empty thing or an 'AAPL' string.

I'm actually wasting time with 'exec' but did not yet come to a solution:

```
    #Main
    df_name=input ('Enetr the name of the DataFrame to be saved as XLS ==>')
    excel_save(exec(df_name))
```

I also tried with exec('df_name') ... No cigars for me so far

The below also did not worked

```
start=dt.date(2017,12,1)
end=dt.date(2018,1,4)
AAPL = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start, end)

AAPL.head()
Out[157]: 
              Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close  \
Date                                                                     
2017-12-01  169.949997  171.669998  168.500000  171.050003  171.050003   
2017-12-04  172.479996  172.619995  169.630005  169.800003  169.800003   
2017-12-05  169.059998  171.520004  168.399994  169.639999  169.639999   
2017-12-06  167.500000  170.199997  166.460007  169.009995  169.009995   
2017-12-07  169.029999  170.440002  168.910004  169.320007  169.320007   

          Volume  
Date                  
2017-12-01  39759300  
2017-12-04  32542400  
2017-12-05  27350200  
2017-12-06  28560000  
2017-12-07  25673300  

df_name=input ('Enter the name of the DataFrame to be saved as XLS ==>')
Enter the name of the DataFrame to be saved as XLS ==>AAPL
df_name
Out[143]: 'AAPL'

final_path
Out[144]: 'C:\\0_Fabio\\Py Shares Data Manager\\Files\\some_name.xls'

df_name.to_excel(final_path)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-146-28a961de7a7e>", line 1, in <module>
df_name.to_excel(final_path)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Thank you so much ! Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understood you want selected `dataframe` files to get saved to a certain path in excel format. If the user input is name of the `dataframe`, you can directly save the `dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'C:\\Files\\'
#main
df_name=input ('Enter the name of the DataFrame to be saved as XLS ==>')
final_path = path + "some_name.xls"
# Note : if type of df_name is just a string, you need to find corresponding data frame and then convert to excel.
df_name.to_excel(final_path)
```

You may put the same in the loop for multiple data frames to get saved and keep changine names.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, Harry, but unfortunately this seems to give as answer an attriburte error:

Comment: It means you are not selecting data frame but a string. So, you basically don't have df_name as data frame rather a string. So, please find the correct corresponding data frame name and try.

Comment: Yep ... I  know and this is exactly where the issue is and where I do not have yet a solution. When in fact the user enters the name of the DataFrame by df_name=input() he gives a string and not a DataFrame. The point is exactly how to use that string from the input() to pass the DataFrame that has the same name of the string to the function that will save the xls file. I added the steps you suggested to the question text above. What I do not know how to do is to convert the sting name to the associated DataFrame (with the same name of the given string).

Comment: Can you please share your code where you already have data frames that matches the string value user assigns ?

Comment: Sure :-) I just added above. The AAPL DataFrame is gathered by the pandas_datareader, the 'AAPL' string is entered by the user by df_name = input().